# Puppet Manifest: Install MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, centos, puppet

I am new to Puppet and writing my first manifest but it gives me an error
whenever an agent tries to communicate with the master.

Couldn't get it right, need some guidance. My OS is centos 7.

My `init.pp`:

```
 package { 'mysql':
          ensure => 'present',
 }

 package { 'php':
          ensure => 'present',
 }

 service { 'mysql':
           ensure => 'running',
 }

 service { 'php':
           ensure => 'running',
 }
```

Comment: What is the error? and What command(s) are you using to run puppet agent?

Comment: The answer I gave you below is very generic. On Stack Overflow, your answer should be more specific. As RaviTezu said, you should at least add what error you get and how you run puppet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to install PHP and MySQL packages of the correct name. In your case, it is `mysql-server`, `php`, and `php-mysql` (or `php5` and `php5-mysql`, e.g.).

Another thing is that you need to start correct services with correct names. It should be `mysqld` for database. The service you start for PHP depends on how you intend to run it - e.g. for running PHP in apache, you may need to start `apache2`.

The third thing that's wrong with your example is that you need to ensure that the services are started only after the respective packages are installed. You can achieve this using `require`, e.g.:

```
service { "mysqld":
    ensure => "running",
    enable => "true",
    require => Package["mysql-server"],
}
```

Lastly, there is more to installing MySQL and PHP than just installing packages and running services. You need to create config files, etc. I would recommend you to use existing modules written for this purpose. For MySQL, there is, e.g., [puppetlabs-mysql](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql), see usage examples there; for PHP on Apache, check out [puppetlabs-apache](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache).

If you want to do things yourself, you can also check out [this tutorial](https://awaseroot.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/puppet-module-for-lamp-installation/) for Ubuntu. Here is an excerpt from the tutorial:

```
Package { ensure => "installed" }

package { "apache2": }
package { "apache2.2-common": }
package { "php5": }
package { "php5-mysql": }
package { "mysql-server": }

exec { "mysqlpasswd":
    command => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password ChangeThis1",
    notify => [Service["mysql"], Service["apache2"]],
    require => [Package["mysql-server"], Package["apache2"]],
}

service { "apache2":
    ensure => "running",
    enable => "true",
    require => Package["apache2"],
}

service { "mysql":
    ensure => "running",
    enable => "true",
    require => Package["mysql-server"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install using the actual package names:

```
package { 'mysql-server':
  ensure => present,
}

package { 'mysql':
  ensure => present,
}

package { 'php-mysql':
  ensure => present,
}
```

and use the correct service name

```
service { 'mysqld':
  ensure => running,
}
```

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#package
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#service

Hope that helps...